# Change WooCommerce registration form/way?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, users, user-registration

I want to change the registration form of WooCommerce a little bit. I'm fine with the normal form which comes from WooCommerce but I want to add the following fields and functions:

If a person enters the email and the password and press register, the person should be redirected to another page where the person is forced to enter the address, phone number and the full name. But how can I do that? I already googled but found nothing... Further, only if the person has entered the details, the confirmtion mail should be send. All that should also be safed with a recaptcher at the end.

Does anybody has an idea how I can solve that?
Would it be possible to redirect the person after entering the email and passwords details to a page where the person is supposed to enter the shipping details and only if those are entered the confirmtion mail gets sended?

Kind Regards and Thank You!

Comment: I found now this one (https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-woocommerce-registration-form-fields/) and implemented it like this. It its also working and I can see my custom WooCommerece fields. But they get displayed above the already existing WooCommerece email and password field. How can I display the custom fields below the already existing fields but above the WooCommerece register button?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying out the same code snippet from Cloudways as well. If you don't use the snippet in functions.php, but instead create a copy of the woocommerce file form-login.php in your child theme's folder/woocommerce/myaccount. Then the fields from the Couldways snippet can be used before the line containing:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a plugin I've been using that lets you add the billing and/or shipping address fields right on the user registration form. It might do what you need, have a look here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-afour/

Comment: sorry, but a link only answer is just not useful in the long term